# Changing organisation for compute engine from workspace to cloud identity

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-workspace

I think I made a big mistake.

I was asked to investigate Office 365 vs workspace and took out a workspace trial. In hindsight, I probably should have created a new workspace account to try this.

To be clear for a long time we have had access to and used the "Google Workspace Admin console" purely to setup our organisation and adminster users for compute engine projects. I am not sure why we would have had access to this without a paid account. (possibly we used g-suite before. It's not clear to me whether companies are able normally able to access this without a paid account.) I assumed this was akin to the free azure organisation/user setup. Nowadays, I believe we would possibly be advised to use Google Identity in this situation.

Having taken out the trial I understand from workspace support that at the end they will delete my existing organisation and users; they cannot not switch me back to an "identity only" version of workspace we seemed to have before, and are therefore forcing me to sign every user up to workspace even though we don't need it at this point. Is this the case or are they advising me incorrectly?

Assuming they are correct, I cannot sign our company up to google identity, since our domain is owned by the soon to be deleted workspace account.
Therefore my worry is that my business is about to lose access to our compute engine organisation and associated logins, as well as google domains.

The only options I can see are to pay for workspace for our users every month, or create a new organisation in cloud identity, transfer the compute engine projects, wait for the workspace account to be removed, then reclaim our main domain and recreate all the admin users. (I am not sure whether we can move a project out of an organisation once there.)

Is this even possible, and what are the dangers? Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a GCP organization and access to the Admin Console, you must have *some* subscription. You can see your subscription(s) in the Admin Console under *Billing > Subscriptions*.

It's possible to add or change subscriptions, but there are some restrictions: For example, if you currently have a *G Suite Legacy* subscription, you might not be offered the ability to add a *Cloud Identity Free* subscription. But there are ways to deal with this -- for example, by temporarily upgrading to a paid plan, and then switching to Cloud Identity Free.

Support should be able to help you find a way that doesn't require deleting and re-creating your account/org.

Comment: You are correct. Support had previously advised me badly, although upon a follow-up contact they corrected this. I have posted another answer explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

Johannes Passing is correct.

admin.google.com on the home page says "Welcome to the Google Workspace Admin console" - this is confusing since the portal is also about administering organisation and users through cloud identity as well (it could be better named for example "Organisation Admin console")

In addition, there are actually different answers from google:-

This one (which I originally read) says "If your trial period ends and you haven’t set up billing or verified your domain, your account will be automatically deleted" and also "You won’t be able to access Google Workspace after completing the steps."

https://support.google.com/a/answer/6388094

...but this one correctly says "Note that cancelling Google Workspace doesn’t remove user accounts, groups, or your organizational structure"

https://support.google.com/a/answer/1257646

Together this gave the impression that access to admin.google.com may be completely removed, if a subscription is removed. I can clearly see that I also have a subscription to Cloud Identity Free.